# What is the correct V7 family for the harmonic progression?

Tags: chord-progressions

The key I am in is B flat Major, and the progression I have is A2, G3, E4, C5, which is the vii7 chord progression. Keeping the sharing notes, what would be the correct V chord? Would it be V6/5, V2, V3/4, or V7?

Comment: Are A2, G3, E4, and C5 the notes making up a single chord? (And do you mean Eb5?)

Answer (score 1):

The `V` chord in `Bb` major is `F-A-C-Eb`. Since the given `vii7` chord has `A` as its lowest pitch, the corresponding `V` chord would be `A-C-Eb-F`, which is V6/5.

In general, `viio7` and `V7` correspond as follows:

```
viio7   ~ V6/5
viio6/5 ~ V4/3
viio4/3 ~ V4/2
```

viio4/2 does not correspond to a V7 chord as it has scale degree 6 as the lowest pitch, and the V7 chord does not contain that pitch.

For a vii7 chord in major (i.e., a half-diminished chord), the correspondence is similar, except that vii7 does not typically serve a dominant function. Nevertheless, the correspondence would be according to the lowest note of the chord.

Answer (score 1):

You've spelled an a minor 7th chord, which doesn't live in B♭ due to the E♮.  However, it DOES live in the key of F, so I think the simplest progression would be something like:

ACEG (amin7)
-> ACE♭F (F7 / A)
-> B♭B♭DF. (B♭)